# SQL Query Running Total in Negative

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with Negative Progress

```
Id  ActivityID  Date   progress
1   x           Jan-10 10
2   y           Jan-10 20
3   x           Feb-10 30
4   y           Feb-10 -5
5   x           Mar-10 -10
6   y           Mar-10 25
7   x           Apr-10 30
8   y           Apr-10 20
9   x           May-10 40
10  y           May-10 40
```

My Intention is to get the Cumulative without the Negatives which I did it:

```
select t1.id,t1.ActivityID,t1.Date,t1.progress,SUM(t2.progress) as sum
from tblIncrement t1
inner join tblIncrement t2
on cast('1.' + t1.date as datetime) >= cast('1.' + t2.date as datetime) and 
t1.ActivityID = t2.ActivityID
where t1.Progress > 0
group by t1.id,t1.activityID,t1.Date,t1.progress
order by t1.ActivityID,cast('1.' + t1.date as datetime)
```

**Result:**

```
id  ActivityID  Date   progress sum
1   x           Jan-10 10       10
3   x           Feb-10 30       40
7   x           Apr-10 30       60
9   x           May-10 40       100
2   y           Jan-10 20       20
6   y           Mar-10 25       40
8   y           Apr-10 20       60
10  y           May-10 40       100
```

My last task is to Get the Periodic Progress from that Sum:

**Intended Result:**

```
id  ActivityID  Date   progress sum Periodic
1   x           Jan-10 10       10  10
3   x           Feb-10 30       40  30
7   x           Apr-10 30       60  20
9   x           May-10 40       100 40
2   y           Jan-10 20       20  20
6   y           Mar-10 25       40  20
8   y           Apr-10 20       60  20
10  y           May-10 40       100 40
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Analytic functions if available could make this much easier.

Comment: What is "periodic progress"?  And I'm befuddled, the sum of the non-negative progresses for x is 110, not 100.  What are the exact rules you are using?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: The `SUM(t2.progress)` includes the Negatives. You can filter those out by adding `AND t2.Progress > 0` to the JOIN. Then Periodic progress would be the same as progress?

Comment: The Concept is not to have a Negative in the Table, and If its the Case the Query Should normalize that Progress to zero and then apply the change in the next month.

Comment: My DBMS is SQL Server 2012

Answer (score 2):

Most databases support the ANSI standard window functions, including cumulative sum.  That makes this easy:

```
select i.*,
       sum(progress) over (partition by activityid order by date) as sumeprogress
from tblIncrement i
where i.progress > 0;
```

I'm not sure what "periodic progress" is.

Comment: Periodic Progress is the Table which I want to Generate from Column "Sum". So for Example in case of ID X the Periodic Result will be 10,30,20,40. As if I am generating the Progress of each Month from the Cumulative. the Process is Actually reversing the Query to not hold Negative Progress.

Comment: I used your query to re-write mine:     

Select * from
    (
    select i.*,sum(progress) over (partition by activityid order by cast('1.' + date as datetime)) as sumeprogress
    from tblIncrement i)t
    where Progress >0
    order by ActivityID,cast('1.' + date as datetime)

What I need is to re-generate the result of "Progress" Column from "sumeprogress"

Comment: @OmarShahineoshahine . . . The difference between the cumulative sums of two adjacent rows is simply the value in any given row.

Answer (score 1):

So does:

```
select t1.id,t1.ActivityID,t1.Date,t1.progress
, SUM(CASE WHEN t1.progress > 0 THEN t2.progress ELSE 0 END) as sum
, SUM(t2.progress) as Periodic
from tblIncrement t1
inner join tblIncrement t2
on cast('1.' + t1.date as datetime) >= cast('1.' + t2.date as datetime) and 
t1.ActivityID = t2.ActivityID
group by t1.id,t1.activityID,t1.Date,t1.progress
order by t1.ActivityID,cast('1.' + t1.date as datetime)
```

do the job for you?

EDIT:

> ...But My intention is to get
>   from "Sum" Column the Progress after excluding the Negative Records.
>   So basically Re-generate the Progress from Cumulative – Omar Shahine
>   oshahine 5 mins ago

Here's my final answer:

```
SELECT t.Id, t.ActivityID, t.Date, t.progress, t.sumprogress 
, t.sumprogress - CASE WHEN (Lag(t.ActivityID) OVER (ORDER BY t.ActivityID, t.ID)) = t.ActivityID THEN Coalesce(Lag(t.sumprogress) OVER (ORDER BY t.ActivityID, t.ID), 0) ELSE 0 END AS Periodic
FROM 
( 
   SELECT i.Id, i.ActivityID, i.Date, i.progress
   , Sum(progress) OVER (PARTITION BY activityid ORDER BY cast('1.' + i.date as DateTime)) as sumprogress 
   FROM tblIncrement i
) AS t 
WHERE Progress > 0 
ORDER BY ActivityID, cast('1.' + t.date as DateTime)
```

I tested it with your test data, and it seems to do the job well.

Comment: I am Getting error:
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near ','.
it seems on:
,SUM(CASE WHEN t1.progress > 0 THEN t2.progress,) as sum

Comment: I've added "End" after Null and it ran,
But My intention is to get from "Sum" Column the Progress after excluding the Negative Records. So basically Re-generate the Progress from Cumulative